# The KDbg is not working/launching on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, kdbg

I am new to assembly language programming, i am reading this book Assembly step by step by Jeff Duntemann. one of his instruction was to download the KDbg for debugging the codes, however when i try to launch the code with kdbg this error occurs again and again for more than 100 times and i do not know what it is.

```
Example: when i run my linked file ./ExampleProgram
like this -> kdbg ExampleProgram i get the following error :

MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
MNG error 11: function is invalid at this point ; chunk MHDR; subcode 0:0
```

can some one please help me to fix this problem. i am new to assembly language programming and the gdb framework. i am using ubuntu on a virtualBox. i have searched the internet and could not find an answer why is the KDbg is not running. Your support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you have installed kdbg from the official ubuntu repository, right?

Comment: No i did not i installed it using the manager

Comment: The version in the repository is the one that is guaranteed to work with your distribution. Install that and see if you still have the error.

Answer (score 8):

You may find this thread helpful https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170379. It suggests to delete icon file `/usr/share/kde4/apps/kdbg/icons/hicolor/22x22/actions/pulse.mng`. Try and see if this solves your problem.

If it doesn't, you can find additional information and updates on this issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdbg/+bug/1311893. As you can see, there it clearly accepts this as a bug in `kdbg` package.

Answer (score 2):

The file "pulse.mng" (an animated image that kdbg uses to show that your program is running) does not work with the current version of kdbg.  The good news is, you can easily generate a fixed version of the file, and the source .png images are provided to do that (at least in Ubuntu 14.04).

```
find /usr/share -name "pulse.mng"
```

Change to the indicated directory and generate a fixed version [(more help here)](https://superuser.com/questions/757830/how-can-i-create-an-mng-file-out-of-pngs)...

```
sudo convert pulse0000??.png pulse-fixed.mng
```

Replace the old "pulse.mng" with your new version, or a link to it.

Here's a gif of the same, which you could alternatively use as the source to `convert`:
[image]